# Flex HistoryManager

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I use HistoryManager in Flex application and during this the HTML title disappears.

How I can set the title in the application?

Best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since HistoryManager and BrowserManager aren't usable in the same app, and if you have to use HistoryManager, it seems that this may be the only option you'll have:

```
ExternalInterface.call("document.title = 'New Title Here'");
```

If you end up being able to use BrowserManager, I expect you would want to use this:

```
var browserManager:IBrowserManager = BrowserManager.getInstance();
browserManager.init("", "Application Title Here");
```

If you need to programmatically alter the title after doing .init() above, simply do the following:

```
browserManager.setTitle("New Title Here");
```